# Simple way to check if a string contains another string in C?

Tags: c, string, substring

I'm pretty new to the language. Let's say I have a string from an HTTP request, such as

```
char * request = "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1";
```

And I specifically want to know if `favicon` is in that request, perhaps with a boolean value. What is a relatively simple way to go about this? I know how to do it in Java, but I'm more lost with C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
if (strstr(request, "favicon") != NULL) {
    // contains
}
```

Comment: Is it bad style to omit `!= NULL`  ?

Comment: don't forget to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @user1011471 Personally I always prefer to be explicit. That way there's never any confusion.

Answer (score 22):

```
strstr(request, "favicon") != NULL
```